# jQuery drag element not updated in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a book type project. I have functions that all users to add annotations to pages, and if necessary drag and drop to make adjustments in their position. The d & d is working successfully. I have a mouseup event bound to the drag div to capture the new location such as left , top etc...

This works fine, later I trigger a function to index all the divs (annotations) present on the page based on class "rect"

```
$.each('.rect',function(){
    addToIndex(this)
})
```

I store all the div properties in an index so they can be recreated when the user returns to the page. This works fine if the div has not been dragged. All properties are correct and can be recreated on the page later.
However if the div has been dragged the div still retains the original properties not the new dragged-to location.

For some reason the dragged div is not being updated in the DOM. 
I can trace the properties for the div after dropping and they are updated
otherwise the div would not be displayed where it was dropped.
How can I force the dropped object to be updated in the DOM using jQuery ?
Do I have to work directly in the DOM in this case instead of jQuery ?

Okay here is more detail

Once the drag object is dropped I capture position and then want to add this as data to the element...snippet here

```
// capturing the literal position of element after dragging

var lx = $(obj).position().left - offPos.left
var uy = $(obj).position().top 
var ux = $(obj).position().left - offPos.left +  $(obj).width()
var ly = $(obj).position().top +  $(obj).height()

var rb = new Array(lx,uy,ux-lx,ly-uy)   

var rbstr = rb.join(",")

// before dragging rbstr value is  593,31,135,40

console.log(rbstr) // outputs 948,13,135,40

//updating the element with new data here

$(obj).attr("data-rb",rbstr)

console.log(rbstr) // outputs 948,13,135,40 which is correct
// everything here indicates the element has been updated
```

But when I try to read all the elements with the same class to store their properties the updated element's properties are not updated but just as they where before the drag and drop.

```
     $.each('.rect',function(){
        var allData = $(this).data()
        console.log($(this).data()) 
       // is correct for all elements except the dragged element
        pageAnnots[thisDoc.currentPage].push(allData)
    })
```

Hope this gives more detail about the problem.Note I can resize the 'rect' and the data gets updated just fine.

Seems to me when the 'rect' is dropped it is a proxy, and updating the data is not happening on the original dragged 'rect'

UPDATE: I found the problem - I was assigning data using

```
 $(this).attr('data-x',n)
```

but then retrieving the data using

```
 $(this)data()
```

Apparently if you assign data using 'attr' you have to likewise retrieve it using the same 'attr' method

Comment: Do you pass string `'.rect'` as parameter to `$.each()` or jQuery object `$(".rect")`?

Comment: More code please. Make a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">

  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>

<input type="Button" name="" value="nextPage" id="next">


</body>
```

jQuery

```
  $(function() {
        $("#draggable").draggable();    

        $("#next").on("click",function() {
            var top = $("#draggable").css("top");
            var bottom = $("#draggable").css("bottom"); 
            var left =   $("#draggable").css("left");
            var right =   $("#draggable").css("right");
            //send them to next page
        });

   });
```

Hope this was what you wanted. The dragable function adds a style attribute to div, if that was what you meant by update DOM.

Comment: I have no problem getting the drag object properties once dropped. I want to assign some data to the object after dropping -